# Ender 3 Power Problem: Not starting up

Tags: creality-ender-3, power-supply, repair

I have a Creality Ender 3, I've had it for just under 2 years and during a print one morning it suddenly stopped and powered itself off. After checking the fuse and other electronic components it still didn't power on. I purchased a new switch as I thought the problem was there but after replacing it is still did not turn on.

The printer has been working fine and there were no visible or audible anomalies. I urgently need this to be fixed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This might be a broken Power supply as much as a broken board. To test: keep the mains power unplugged, connect the front USB port to a PC. If you get a screen, the board is ok. Just get a new Power supply in that case.

Comment: Ok, I will try that.

Comment: Is anything abnormal here: the power supply?

Comment: Is anything abnormal: Power supply - link to google drive as image too big  : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4i3vetngZX0VUQyc21HZkR2bzF3amFuQkViLUN5azM0NnNN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I am not an electrician, but the 8A/230V fuse of the Power supply seems to be intact. **Do NOT work with mains voltage unless you have undergone the necessary training to do so! Take all the necessary precautions as you need to work with electricity under mains voltage!** Thomas has a tutorial on what might be needed to repair them. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gHBpDxf6eVA

Comment: I think it may be wise to invest in a [multimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimeter), you would then be able to check if the PSU outputs 12/24 V (depending on the output voltage).

Comment: Does the outlet that you're plugging it into have power? (Yea this happened to me once with my Anet A8)

Comment: @TimLi When you buy a multimeter, note that although many 3D printers work from 12 V (as mentioned by 0scar), an Ender 3 uses a 24 V PSU. A convenient place to measure is found by disconnecting (with the PSU switched off) the yellow connector.

Comment: Purchased new power supply after testing he board. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@trish Thankyou for your help.

I did purchased the new power supply and everything works fine now.